# Ruby module behaves differently on linux and windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following module on my ruby-on-rails 3.0.5 (running on ruby 1.9.5)

```
require 'openssl'

module Crypto
  def self.create_keys(priv = "rsa_key", pub = "#{priv}_pub", bits = 1024)
    private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(bits)
    File.open(priv, "w+") { |fp| fp << private_key.to_s }
    File.open(pub,  "w+") { |fp| fp << private_key.public_key.to_s }
    private_key
  end

  def self.file_exist?
    File.exist?('rsa_key') && File.exist?('rsa_key_pub')
  end

  class Key
    def initialize(data)
      @public = (data =~ /^-----BEGIN (RSA|DSA) PRIVATE KEY-----$/).nil?
      @key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(data)
      Rails.logger.debug "STOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP"
    end

    def self.from_file(filename)
      file = File.new( filename )
      self.new file.read
    end

    def encrypt(text)
      Base64.encode64(@key.send("#{key_type}_encrypt", text))
      #@key.send("#{key_type}_encrypt", text)
    end

    def decrypt(text)
      @key.send("#{key_type}_decrypt", Base64.decode64(text))
      #@key.send("#{key_type}_decrypt", text)
    end

    def private?
      !@public
    end

    def public?
      @public
    end

    def key_type
      @public ? :public : :private
    end

    def key
      @key
    end
  end
end
```

Running this code on my local machine (windows) and on the server (linux) results in:

```
priv_key = Crypto::Key.from_file('rsa_key')
@pqp = priv_key.key_type
```

Windows: Private
Linux: Public

But both versions shows the same thing if I do `priv_key.key.to_s`
Someone knows what is happening? Being trying to fix that for two days.

---

Found the problem, removing the end of string character in the regular expression solved everything.

```
def initialize(data)
    @public = (data =~ /^-----BEGIN (RSA|DSA) PRIVATE KEY-----/).nil?
    @key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(data)
end
```

The regular expression works correctly in windows, rubular and any other checks.
I leave the question open for anyone that can find why it don't works in Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that you should be able to pare this down into a much smaller test case. Much of that code isn't even used.

Comment: Note that you can (and should) replace your implementation of `from_file` with `def self.from_file(filename); self.new(IO.read(filename)); end`, since the code you have never closes the file handle.

Comment: Sorry @Phrogz , that module was something I found on the internet. But how could I do a simpler test than opening a key and checking it's type?

Oh, I changed the from_file because since it was giving some errors I thought it might not be opening the file at all, before it was like:

    `def self.from_file(filename)`
        `self.new(File.read(filename));`
    `end`

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: @Phrogz Did some more checks and the point is, on linux the line `(data =~ /^-----BEGIN (RSA|DSA) PRIVATE KEY-----$/)` always return nil. On Windows it returns 0 (which is the begin of the string, correct). As a mater of fact data is correctly loaded as `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MYPRIVATEKEYHERE -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----